# Global Submission validation based on a select item

Tags: webforms

Is there a way to get Drupal 7 / Webforms to block a submission for a duplicate answer in a previous submission.  I am sending an application questionnaire to multiple app owners, the form is setup with a listbox containing the App name, then the rest of the form is generic for each app.  I would like for the App owners to not be able to accidentally submit for the same app twice.

Many people have suggested the "Webform Validation" module, but as far as I can tell, it only does validation on the form itself.  It cannot do validation for the form being submitted against previously submitted forms.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, Webform supports this out of the box.

Edit the "app name" field and under "Validation" select the "Unique" checkbox:

> Check that all entered values for this field are unique. The same value is not allowed to be used twice.

This will make sure that each webform entry has a unique value for this field, meaning that duplicates will not be allowed.

---

UPDATE

Here is a sample code that will allow you to validate the webform submissions.

Create a new folder called `custom` in `sites/all/modules`, and then another folder called `sample` in `custom`.

Place the following in `sample.info` file:

```
name = Sample
description = Sample custom module that provides custom webform validation rules.
package = Custom
core = 7.x
version = 7.x-1.0
```

Place the following in `sample.module` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function sample_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Make sure that we are selecting the webform forms.
  if (substr($form_id, 0, 20) == 'webform_client_form_') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'sample_webform_validate';
  }
}

/**
 * Sample validation callback.
 */
function sample_webform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Replace this with the name of your field, cid (webform component ID) and
  // nid.
  $field_name = 'select_something';
  $cid = 1;
  $nid = 4;
  // Check if this is a duplicate.
  $is_duplicate = db_select('webform_submitted_data', 'd')
    ->fields('d')
    ->condition('nid', $nid)
    ->condition('cid', $cid)
    ->condition('data', $form_state['values']['submitted'][$field_name])
    ->execute()
    ->fetchObject();
  if ($is_duplicate) {
    form_set_error($field_name, t('Duplicate value, please select something else.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I clicked on the Application Name Field, selected "Edit" and when I scroll down to "Validation" it only has one option titled "Required" which can be checked or unchecked.  This is Drupal 7, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is the "Application Name" field a textfield? You can see my screenshot with a note [here](http://i.imgur.com/9Sz5NPa.png).

Comment: No, it's a Type: Select Options that I have displayed as a listbox.  I checked one of my textfield's validation options and it does have the unique options, I guess it's disabled on "select options
"

Comment: This is a pretty good thread on it, I guess it's a no-can-do via the UI right now   https://www.drupal.org/node/1151516

Comment: Sorry, now I see that you mentioned that the "App Name" is a select box. Well, I still think you could do this using a custom module. I'll update my answer to show you the direction.

Comment: So my php skills are lacking to say the least, could you tell me which specific file I should update with this piece of code?  I think I can figure it out from there.

Comment: I updated the answer; this should go in a custom module. You can replace `sample` with anything else, just make sure that you rename function names, `.module` and `.info` files, and the folder itself.

Comment: I updated all the variables for my db, but when I enable the module it throws all the code above the header on every page.  I took a screenshot  http://imgur.com/o2A5Bjd

Comment: What do you mean by "I updated all the variables for my db"? Where did you put the code from my answer?

Comment: I created the /custom/sample folders and placed the .info and .module files in that folder.  When I enable that module, all of the code appears at the top of my drupal page as the screenshot shows. And by "updating the vairiables" I mean I changed the $fieldname, $cid, and $nid to match the field in my db.

Comment: so, in other words, i queried the webform_component table and got the nid,cid, and field name for the options I want to check for dupes and updated your sample.module with that new info.

Comment: Well, I figured it out, I had it add the opening <?php tag to the beginning of the code you linked, thanks so much for your help Topsitemakers...you are the man!!!

Comment: Glad I helped :)